# I'm new in developing responsive Wordpress Theme, so which framework to use or work from scratch?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

I'm totally new in developing responsive Wordpress Theme sector. But fortunately, I've heard of Frameworks like: Underscore, child-themes, Genesis !!

What speciality each Framework has? I'm much confused about that, are these frameworks suitable for designing latest WP versions or just legacy Wordpress versions? like WP 3.0 or WP 3.3, so need some experts opinions here.

I'm actually confused about developing a responsive Wordpress Theme in a short period of time & also compounding that I don't have knowledge of which Wordpress Theme Development Framework goes for which Wordpress versions? so everyone, plz bear with my question & answer me positively... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad and totally relies on personal opinions, and not known facts. Please see [ask] and [help] for additional info which topics to avoid here

Comment: Do **not** multi post the same question.

Comment: to express this question of mine properly, I've to elaborate, there is no shortcut...if otherwise, then give me good suggestions, not just comments...OK !!

Comment: Reread you question and check if you can properly answer it with **facts** in three short paragraphs. ;-)

Comment: Ok, I've already done that...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to which framework *you* should use is — no one knows.

From code perspective there is certain degree of baseline theme functionality/experience — enforced by formal standards. Those things are recommended/required for inclusion into official theme directory, outside of that people can do things a little more lax.

Frameworks exist for different reasons. Roughly I would say that the broad categories are:

- providing additional functionality
- helping with code reuse
- accommodating specific technologies

There is no "best" or "right" framework because then we would only need one.

Versions are pretty irrelevant. Frameworks tend to be made by intermediate to advanced developers/agencies. They are either decently maintained or discontinued altogether.

In a nutshell you'll need to conduct your own research and evaluate frameworks, fitting your requirements, yourself. This is not something someone else can pick for you.